# How can MTR scriptly tracroutes multiple hosts ( one network )?

Tags: traceroute

[image: mtr]

As picture showed above, since mtr can only traceroute one host once, how can I "scan" the whole network (172.16.0.0/16) and find all the hosts which only got 2 hops, with a script? 
Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For those who may need it, the simple way:
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should copy/paste text instead of showing scripts as an image -> downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
  
touch result

for ip in 172.16.{35..254}.{1..254}
do
        echo "Trying $ip ... "
        hops=$( mtr -c 5 -r -n4 -T $ip | wc -l )
        if [[ "$hops" == 4 ]]; then
                echo "Yes!"
                echo $ip >> result
        fi
done
```